# Working Audio Loop Example in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm trying to use Dart to get an OGG file to loop using the HTML5 `<audio>` element. Does anyone have a working example for this. I'm specifically having trouble getting the audio to loop.

Comment: Can you please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to have a fully controlled loop using the html5 AudioElement; sometimes the loop option was simply not working, sometimes there was a gap, sometimes patterns would overlap.

I had better chance using WebAudio using something like:

```dart
source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = buffer;

gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 1;

source.connectNode(gainNode);
gainNode.connectNode(audioContext.destination);

// play it now in loop
source.start(audioContext.currentTime);
source.loop = true;
```

I was not able to load the source buffer from the html audio element which could have been a solution for the CORS issues I had. The samples were loaded using http requests.

I created a dartpad example that demonstrates looping using AudioElement native loop feature and WebAudio

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/879424bca794c63698b0